How to properly define a recursive type in TypeScript
I want to define function types where the functions form part of a group such that the group contains pointers to the functions (and potentially other values) based on some parameter.
The following is a basic representation of what I'm trying to achieve:
type ValueGroup = Record<string, unknown>
type ValueGroupCreationCallback = (...args: any[]) => ValueGroup

export class ValueGroupFactory<
  CreationCallback extends ValueGroupCreationCallback
> {
  creationCallback: CreationCallback

  constructor(creationCallback: CreationCallback) {
    this.creationCallback = creationCallback
  }

  createGroup(...params: Parameters<CreationCallback>) {
    return this.creationCallback.call(
      null,
      ...params
    ) as ReturnType<CreationCallback>
  }
}

function member1(g: ReturnType<typeof factory.createGroup>, string: string) {
  // Error
  return [string, g]
}

function member2(g: ReturnType<typeof factory.createGroup>, number: number) {
  // Error
  return [number, g]
}

const factory = new ValueGroupFactory((name: string) => {
  // Error
  const group = {
    person: { name },
    get member1() {
      // Error: 'member1' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation...
      return member1.bind(null, group)
    },

    get member2() {
      // Error: 'member2' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation...
      return member2.bind(null, group)
    }
  }

  return group
})

const group1 = factory.createGroup("John") // Has type `any` instead of { person, member1, ... }

Playground
The goal is to make the functions callable through their group by passing the exact parameters they require for their specific operations (through binding) and not other values that might not be primary to what they do. I've tried several approaches to no avail. TS just assigns the values the type any. I would like to get rid of the getters too if possible. How am I supposed to be implementing this?
EDIT: So, the following explains the need better.
The first thing is the functions that are supposed to exist in the group are normal top-level functions that only do a single thing in a normal FP manner. For example, there can be a function like toggleVisibility() which causes whatever element passed to it to be hidden either by adding or removing a class. The function is a top-level function (in the module containing it) and is not part of any class, so no this. It's just a normal utility function that knows how to add/remove a specific class.
However, I have provided a way for users of the library to define custom prefixes for classes used by the library via JS (as classes are emitted from JS). So, toggleVisibility now needs access to that prefix. Also, there may be multiple instantiations of the lib on a single page, which is why there's a group factory, each instantiation with its group. The point is, that I want the functions (e.g. toggleVisibility) to mostly retain the same API surface. The only difference now would be to call g.toggleVisibility() with g being a newly-created group. And if toggleVisibility also calls another top-level function like addClass("visibility-toggle") which does the actual addition of the class, it just does it as g.addClass("visibility-toggle") instead of something like this.addClass("visibility-toggle") or addClass.call(group, "visibility-toggle"), where "visibility-toggle" is not the actual class on the element, but one to be prefixed.
Both toggleVisibility and addClass will exist on the group, but with the group already bound to them, so the parameters passed when calling them would be the actual ones that are pertinent to their core functionalities.
A simple representation of the pattern I'm describing is shown below (not typesafe, for description only):
function hasClass(g, element, classID) {
  // Some check that returns boolean
}

function addClass(g, element, classID) {
  // Some class addition logic
}

function removeClass(g, element, classID) {
  // Some class removal logic
}

function toggleVisibility(g, element) {
  if (g.hasClass(element, "visibility-toggle"))
    g.removeClass(element, "visibility-toggle")
  else g.addClass(element, "visibility-toggle")
}

// `DangerAlert` is basically a component, and can be called with multiple `configs`
function DangerAlert(config: { classPrefix }) {
  // Group factory would be some already defined factory
  const g = dangerAlertGroupFactory.createGroup({ classPrefix: config.classPrefix })
  const renderableElement = document.createElement("div")
  setInterval(() => g.toggleVisibility(renderableElement), 1000)
}

From here, once g is created, all member functions on it can access it, as the process of createGroup binds the group to the functions.
I hope this makes sense.

Thanks @jcalz I've updated the question

• I'm trying to understand what this code is supposed to do, but your definitions are circular. I feel like I'm just as confused as TS is here. What types do you expect to see here? How do you plan to use group1()? • "I would like to get rid of the getters too if possible." Is that a second question or something? Make sure you're only asking one well-defined question here.

@jcalz Basically, I have something want something like. There is some sort of rendering that happens, and the value of name differs based on props from each render (not React btw). So, I want to create a group such that all values (particularly functions) that depend on values that change with each render e.g person: { name: string } are on that group, and once the group is created, I don't have to pass down the value of person down through each function when I call them, also the functions can call other functions on the group simply through g.someFunc, if that makes sense.

It's basically like this, but as a parameter isn't of actual this. I'm avoiding classes (and creating the functions as methods) intentionally.

In other words, I wish TS would defer the resolution of ReturnType<typeof factory.createGroup> in the parameter types instead of resolving it eagerly (as I understand it)

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining (but I guess I'm missing the point where you, for some reason, pass group into an out of a function without modifying it, or what the point of doing that is). If not, please [edit] to make it clear what's missing there.

(See prev comment) It's also possible that you're looking for something like this, where I use chaining to relieve TS from having to do anything truly circular. If that is what you want, let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

So @jcalz I've just edited the question to make the need clearer.  The solutions you shared rely on the functions being defined directly on the group (or am I wrong?), but I want the functions to be normal top-level functions, just bound to the group in the group creation process.

Also, @jcalz Passing the group into and out of the function is merely coincidental. It's not part of the required pattern. I just wanted to return some value from the function.

You want the functions to be "normal top-level functions" where the first parameter type is... what? You want it presumably to be inferred from somewhere, but there are limits on the kinds of anonymous types you can reference without being circular. My second suggestion (slightly modified) gives you something pretty close, where the first parameter type is inferred contextually. It's not clear why you care about it being "top level" in that way; there's nothing this-context happening. If you require top level functions then you need to defined your type.

(see prev comment) Furthermore, passing the group into the function isn't coincidental, right? It's the whole point. Maybe you mean out of the function is coincidental, but then you could always [edit] not to do that; certainly there are a zillion other things you can return from the function (like I just showed in my playground link in the prev comment).  At this point I think I've exhausted my ability to come up with alternatives. Either you declare your types explicitly with top-level functions, or you use helpers for inference using callbacks. How should we proceed here?

Yeah @jcalz. Passing the group into the function isn't coincidental, yes, my bad. I only meant out of the function. Not sure how to proceed too lol, but thanks.
I want the functions to remain top-level because, based on the kind of functions I want to use in the pattern, I think it makes most sense for them to be top-level. Also, I know there's nothing happening with this. Maybe what I'm looking for isn't possible then without explicitly defining types.

You haven't really explained why you want the thing you want. "I think it makes most sense" sounds nice, but given that it's not possible without doing something else you don't want, it seems like you've overconstrained your problem. Your example with hasClass() can be implemented using my suggestion like this and it works and behaves as desired with the exception that instead of top level, it's arrow functions. Like ‍♂️, if that's not good enough for you, then I give up. I can write up that as a suggested answer or just disengage at this point. It's up to you.

Maybe I've overconstrained the problem as you said. Thanks anyway. I would say the approach in that suggestion isn't particularly what I'm looking for, but it could be for someone having a similar problem. So, I think it's good to put it up as a suggested answer.

Another thing is that this works: const factory = new ValueGroupFactory(() => ({ member1, member2 })). Here, TS know not to resolve the type of member1 and member2 directly and allow that recursive definition.

"this works", can you show me as a [mre]? I need to see it somewhere.

An example is here.
Also, take a look at this @jcalz. There are two definitions of factory there. The first definition returns a direct value and it works. The second stores it in an intermediate variable and it doesn't.

Btw, I figured out a solution using class. I wrote up an answer about it. Thanks for helping out.

I thought you were intentionally avoiding classes. Oh well.

Yes, @jcalz. I said, " I'm avoiding classes (and creating the functions as methods) intentionally". I meant that I didn't want the functions to be methods. I want them to remain top-level.

So the problem is that TS is always trying to resolve the group type defined in the question ReturnType<typeof factory.createGroup> instead of deferring it, which would cause it to throw circularity errors. I found the following simple solution.
function member1(g: Group, b: string) {}
function member2(g: Group, b: number) {}

class Group {
  member1
  member2

  constructor() {
    this.member1 = member1.bind(null, this)
    this.member2 = member2.bind(null, this)
  }
}

const g = new Group()
g.member1("")
g.member2(87)

Here, TS allows using the class instance type (Group) as the parameter type and doesn't eagerly try to resolve it (which would cause circularity issues since the type of Group is based on the type of member1, and vice versa).
